# How to retrieve a particular dictionary within a list, from index?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries within a dictionary. Here is an example of how the first two nested dictionaries in the list appear:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "waypoints_geoJSONtest",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 1.0, "point": "001", "time": "2020\/03\/05 16:17:11.000", "elevation": 68.171204, "notes_plan": null, "notes_lulc": null, "notes_medi": null, "notes_othe": "Inicio trayecto", "Category": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -78.759113, 9.034811 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 2.0, "point": "002", "time": "2020\/03\/05 16:22:53.000", "elevation": 76.204994, "notes_plan": "Cuipo", "notes_lulc": null, "notes_medi": null, "notes_othe": null, "Category": "Plantas" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -78.759178, 9.034232 ] } },
```

As you can see, "features" contains a list of dictionaries (starting on line 5). What I am having trouble doing is accessing the first dictionary through indexing. I have tried this:

```
for listcontents in data["features"]:
    print(listcontents[1])
```

Which just returns

```
KeyError: 1
```

I am confused about why I can't just call a dictionary based on index, since it's in a list. I know that dictionaries are unordered, but since the dictionaries are within an ordered list, shouldn't I just be able to call a dict based on position in the list?

Comment: ```listcontents``` is the dictionary.  it's equivalent to ```data["features"][0]``` for the first iteration

Comment: you can use `data["features"][1]`

Comment: @ewong ah, this is what I misunderstood (that we're already within the first dictionary when we call `listcontents` in `data["features"]`). I thought listcontents was every dictionary within the list.

Answer (score 0):

Brenda Thompson I just made some changes to data, it is missing with some closing brackets, I hope you are this solution will help you :)

```
data = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "name": "waypoints_geoJSONtest",
            "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" }},
            "features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 1.0, "point": "001", "time": "2020\/03\/05 16:17:11.000", "elevation": 68.171204, "notes_plan": None, "notes_lulc": None, "notes_medi": None, "notes_othe": "Inicio trayecto", "Category": None }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -78.759113, 9.034811 ] } },{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 2.0, "point": "002", "time": "2020\/03\/05 16:22:53.000", "elevation": 76.204994, "notes_plan": "Cuipo", "notes_lulc": None, "notes_medi": None, "notes_othe": None, "Category": "Plantas" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -78.759178, 9.034232 ] } }],
        }
for i in data["features"]:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'fid': 1.0, 'point': '001', 'time': '2020\\/03\\/05 16:17:11.000', 'elevation': 68.171204, 'notes_plan': 
None, 'notes_lulc': None, 'notes_medi': None, 'notes_othe': 'Inicio trayecto', 'Category': None}, 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-78.759113, 9.034811]}}
{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'fid': 2.0, 'point': '002', 'time': '2020\\/03\\/05 16:22:53.000', 'elevation': 76.204994, 'notes_plan': 
'Cuipo', 'notes_lulc': None, 'notes_medi': None, 'notes_othe': None, 'Category': 'Plantas'}, 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-78.759178, 9.034232]}}
```

As per requirement if you need access to data by index then use this code

```
data = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "name": "waypoints_geoJSONtest",
            "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" }},
            "features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 1.0, "point": "001", "time": "2020\/03\/05 16:17:11.000", "elevation": 68.171204, "notes_plan": None, "notes_lulc": None, "notes_medi": None, "notes_othe": "Inicio trayecto", "Category": None }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -78.759113, 9.034811 ] } },{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 2.0, "point": "002", "time": "2020\/03\/05 16:22:53.000", "elevation": 76.204994, "notes_plan": "Cuipo", "notes_lulc": None, "notes_medi": None, "notes_othe": None, "Category": "Plantas" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -78.759178, 9.034232 ] } }],
        }
for i in range(len(data["features"])):
    print(data["features"][i])
```